# Validating one div and allowing to move to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page which has multiple divs. I am showing each div once at a time and showing by providing next and previous traversing buttons. Whenever I click next, I want the elements in that div to get validated. I had included oninvalid function inside every input; But I am not sure how to map them to next and previous buttons.

```
<form method="post">
<div id="divs">
<div id="div1">
<fieldset>
<legend>User Details</legend>
<p><label for="id">ID</label>
<input type="text" name="usermail" pattern="[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Enter your ID" required id="id" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your 9 digit id')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></p>           
<p><label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required id="email" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your email id')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></p>
</fieldset>     
</div>

<div id="div2">    
<fieldset>
<legend>Add Rooms</legend>
<p><label>Select Room</label>   
<input type="text" name="Room No." pattern="[0-9]{3}" placeholder="Enter Room No." required id="roomid" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the Room No.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></p> 
</p>  
</fieldset>
</div>

<div id="div3"> 
<fieldset>
<legend>Add Building No.</legend>
<p><label>Select Building</label>  
<input type="text" name="Building No." pattern="[0-9]{2}" placeholder="Enter building no." required id="buildingid" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the Building No.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"></p> 
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Next" id="next">
<input type="submit" value="Previous" id="prev" style="display: none;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

The script to traverse between next and previous button is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#prev").hide();
$("#divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }            
}); 

$("#next").click(function(){
    $("#divs div:visible").hide().next().show();
    if ($("#divs div:visible").next().length == 0) {
        $("#next").hide();
        $("#submit").show();
    }

    $("#prev").show();

});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    $("#divs div:visible").hide().prev().show();
    if ($("#divs div:visible").prev().length == 0) {
        $("#prev").hide();
    }

    $("#next").show();
    $("#submit").hide();
});
});

</script>
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!!

Comment: @BigChris Asynchronous JavaScript And eXtensible Markup Language? More like 6 words `:)`... Also, not sure what this post has to do with ajax.

Comment: I was trying to extend my comment but ran out of time so I couldn't submit it. I said to use AJAX as I can see jQuery is being used and it's easier to get the server to validate and send a single "form is valid" response to enable the "next" button to progress to the next section. Using solely client-side validation is a little trickier and the OP's JS will be considerably more complicated. Server-side will provide the separation between data and presentation (best practice)...